# Cannot compile Flink 1.7.2 for Scala 2.12: Maven enforcer finds banned dependencies

Tags: scala, maven, apache-flink, maven-enforcer-plugin

I'm trying to compile Flink 1.7.2 for Scala 2.12, in order to get the AWS Kinesis connector, which is excluded from the binary distributions, as stated [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/connectors/kinesis.html).

I downloaded the source code from [here](https://flink.apache.org/downloads.html) and used the following command:

```
mvn clean install -Pscala-2.12 -Pinclude-kinesis -DskipTests
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M1:enforce (enforce-versions) @ flink-runtime_2.12 ---
[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.BannedDependencies failed with message:
Found Banned Dependency: com.typesafe.akka:akka-testkit_2.12:jar:2.4.20
Found Banned Dependency: com.typesafe.akka:akka-remote_2.12:jar:2.4.20
Found Banned Dependency: org.scala-lang.modules:scala-java8-compat_2.12:jar:0.8.0
Found Banned Dependency: com.typesafe:ssl-config-core_2.12:jar:0.2.1
Found Banned Dependency: org.clapper:grizzled-slf4j_2.12:jar:1.3.2
Found Banned Dependency: com.github.scopt:scopt_2.12:jar:3.5.0
Found Banned Dependency: org.apache.flink:flink-queryable-state-client-java_2.12:jar:1.7.2
Found Banned Dependency: com.typesafe.akka:akka-protobuf_2.12:jar:2.4.20
Found Banned Dependency: com.twitter:chill_2.12:jar:0.7.6
Found Banned Dependency: org.scalatest:scalatest_2.12:jar:3.0.0
Found Banned Dependency: com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.12:jar:2.4.20
Found Banned Dependency: com.typesafe.akka:akka-slf4j_2.12:jar:2.4.20
Found Banned Dependency: org.scalactic:scalactic_2.12:jar:3.0.0
Found Banned Dependency: com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream_2.12:jar:2.4.20
Found Banned Dependency: org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:jar:1.0.5
Found Banned Dependency: org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.12:jar:1.0.4
Use 'mvn dependency:tree' to locate the source of the banned dependencies.
```

I don't understand why these dependencies are being banned, as the `pom.xml`, inside the `scala-2.12` profile, the dependencies are banned in this way:

```
<!-- make sure we don't have any _2.10 or _2.11 dependencies when building
for Scala 2.12 -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>enforce-versions</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <rules>
                    <bannedDependencies>
                        <excludes combine.children="append">
                            <exclude>*:*_2.11</exclude>
                            <exclude>*:*_2.10</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </bannedDependencies>
                </rules>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Previously, I successfully compiled Flink for Scala 2.11. To make sure that my environment was not polluted from this previous compilation, I deleted and re-downloaded the Flink sources, and I completely wiped out the `.m2` Maven cache.

Answer (score 2):

This is a flink bug fixed only in 1.9.0, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-12007 for details.

As a workaround, build with `mvn clean install -Pinclude-kinesis -DskipTests -Pscala-2.12 -Dscala-2.12`. And remember to use JDK8 for the build.